# websocket works with http module but not with express (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, websocket

I'm trying to make websokects work with node.js using express and websocket modules.
The funny thing is that if I use the http module to create the server they work as expected, I receive status 101.
But if I use the express module to create the server it'll throw an error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2345/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here's the code

```
// using http module (works)
var WebSocketServer = require("websocket").server;
var http = require("http");

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

    response.end(""+
    "<!DOCTYPE html>"+
    "<html>"+
        "<head>"+
            "<script>"+
                "var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2345/');"+
                "ws.onmessage = function(event) { "+
                "var span = document.createElement('span');"+
                "span.innerHTML = event.data;"+
                "document.body.appendChild(span);"+
                "}"+
            "</script>"+
        "</head>"+
        "<body>"+
            "<span>Messages: </span>"+
        "</body>"+
    "</html>"
    );
});

app.listen(2345);

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({'httpServer':app});

wsServer.on("request", function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    console.log("Connection ACCEPTED\n");

    connection.on("message", function(message)
    {
        if(message.type == 'utf8')
        {
            console.log("Received Message: %s", message.utf8Data);
            connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        }
    })

    connection.on("close", function(reasonCode, description)
    {
        console.log("Connection lost\n");
    })
})
```

and the non working part

```
// using express module (get error)
var WebSocketServer = require("websocket").server;
var app = require('express')();

var app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

    response.end(""+
    "<!DOCTYPE html>"+
    "<html>"+
        "<head>"+
            "<script>"+
                "var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2345/');"+
                "ws.onmessage = function(event) { "+
                "var span = document.createElement('span');"+
                "span.innerHTML = event.data;"+
                "document.body.appendChild(span);"+
                "}"+
            "</script>"+
        "</head>"+
        "<body>"+
            "<span>Messages: </span>"+
        "</body>"+
    "</html>"
    );
});

app.listen(2345);

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({'httpServer':app});

wsServer.on("request", function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    console.log("Connection ACCEPTED\n");

    connection.on("message", function(message)
    {
        if(message.type == 'utf8')
        {
            console.log("Received Message: %s", message.utf8Data);
            connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        }
    })

    connection.on("close", function(reasonCode, description)
    {
        console.log("Connection lost\n");
    })
})
```

What could be wrong there? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app` in Express is not the `httpServer`, so if the `WebSocketServer` doesn't explicitly know about Express and how to get the server from it, then you probably need to give it the actual `httpServer` object rather than the `Express` object which you can do by changing this:

```
app.listen(2345);
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({'httpServer':app});
```

to this:

```
var server = app.listen(2345);
var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({'httpServer': server});
```